# Error trying to run a javascript program from the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a javascript file prompt.js from the terminal but I'm getting this error.

```
$ node prompt.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'prompt'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pathwang/Documents/School/Spring2019/CSC404/CSC404_MyHomework/Patrick_Hwang_CSC404_Hw1/prompt.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

This is what is in my prompt.js file:

```
 var prompt = require('prompt');
 var schema = {
    properties: {
      name: {
        pattern: /^[a-zA-Z\s\-]+$/,
        message: 'Name must be only letters, spaces, or dashes',
        required: true
      },
      email: {

      },
      exam1: { type: 'number'},
      exam2: { type: 'number'},
      exam3: { type: 'number'}
    }
  };

  var student = {
    name: '',
    id: '',
    exam1: 60,
    exam2: 60,
    exam3: 60,
    at1: true,
    at2: true,
    at3: true,
    at4: true,
    at5: true,
    adjust: true,
    final: 100,
    letter: ' '
  };

  //
  // Get two properties from the user: username and email
  //
  prompt.get(schema, function (err, result) {
    //
    // Log the results.
    //
    console.log('Command-line input received:');
    console.log('  username: ' + result.username);
    console.log('  email: ' + result.email);
    console.log('  exam1:', result.exam1);
    console.log('  exam2:', result.exam2);
    console.log('  exam3:', result.exam3);
    var totalExam;

    totalExam = (1/3) * (result.exam1 + 
                         result.exam2 + 
                         result.exam3);
    console.log(' Average exam =', totalExam )

  });

 //
  // Start the prompt
  //
  prompt.start();
```

I'm in the right directory and I can run other files in the project folder by using `$ node test.js`. I also can open prompt.js file from the terminal in a different project folder where I copied the source code from. I don't know why this is happening? I would appreciate the help thanks.

Comment: It sounds like there's an error in prompt.js.

Comment: I opened prompt.js in another project folder the same way. Then I made a new prompt.js file in a different project folder and copied and pasted the code to the new prompt.js file in the different project folder and I'm getting this error?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what's inside `prompt.js`?

Comment: Yea, so, this line is failing `var prompt = require('prompt');`. it's saying it can't find said module. or, in other words, said module is not part of said project. it doesn't exist. it hasn't been installed. it's not there.

Comment: Appreciate the help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line var prompt = require('prompt'); causing the error. The error is saying it can't find said module. Or the module is not part of the project it doesn't exist. The solution is to find the module called prompt and add the directory into the project folder. This will solve the problem.